# Return a String array on a JNI method

Tags: android, arrays, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I need to get a List of Strings (char*) from C++ and return it to Java.

How can I do that?

I think one solution is return a big string pre-defined like: "[item1][item2]" and make a split on Java, but it doesn't look like the right approach.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Look at `NewObjectArray` into the JNI doc.

Basically you can return from the JNI function an Array Of String (Java) an then transform it in a `List` or a whatever kind of Collection type.

Peudo code:

Java:

```
....
public List<String> getFooAsList(){
  return new ArrayList(this.getData());
}  
private native String[] getData();
```

JNI

```
#include <jni.h>


  JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL 
               como_foo_bar_getData
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj){

    jobjectArray ret;
    int i;

    char *data[5]= {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    ret= (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(5,env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),env->NewStringUTF(""));

    for(i=0;i<5;i++) env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,i,env->NewStringUTF(data[i]));

    return(ret);
 }
```

Not tested!!!

Let me know if it works for u

Regards

Comment: Just one more question, what is the data type I use in my jni_onLoad bind method? { "getTOC", "()<here>", reinterpret_cast<void*>(& Java_com_rmsdk_wrapper_RMServices_getTOC)}

Comment: I just found it's "()[Ljava/lang/String;"

Comment: Another question: what happens if `SetObjectArrayElement` throws an exception? How does the allocated array get cleaned up? Do you return `ret` or `NULL`?

Comment: char *data[5]= {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}; is now deprecated.this will show warning messages in the gradle console.

Answer (score 5):

```
ret= (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(5,env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),env->NewStringUTF(""));
```

I think the initial element initialized to "" (empty string)

```
env->NewStringUTF("")
```

is not needed, as you assign a new value to the array element just after:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,i,env->NewStringUTF(data[i]));
```

A simple "NULL" would be enough in this case, as the initial element specified will be electable for garbage collection as soon as the next line is executed. It's like writing the following in Java code:

```
int i = 0;
i = 1;
```

Or worse:

```
Object object = new BigObjectVeryHeavyToInitialize();
object = new AnotherObject();
```

Your favorite IDE would issue you a little warning for that.

Comment: Precisely. The memory allocation done for the empty initialization strings might lead to memory leak, as they are not deleted automatically.