# Return vector<string> from c++ to Java

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to learn android ndk. Below is my Java method :

```
public static native Vector<String>     GetData(String input) ;
```

'input'(input parameter) will go to the c++ native method which will return a vector. How do I implement the c++ side of the method?

Comment: What's the character set and encoding for your strings? `NewStringUTF ` expects _modified_ UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It would be easier to use an array and not a vector:

```
    public static native String[] getData(String input);
```

2) Lets assume your Java package name is com.example.jeff and you have a class named MyCppFacade that contains getData(). You need to create a C++ file that contains this function:

```
    extern "C" jobjectArray Java_com_example_jeff_MyCppFacade_getData(
    JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring input)
    {
         jobjectArray result;
         ...
         return result;
    }
```

3) To create your string array you could look at [Return a String array on a JNI method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047166/return-a-string-array-on-a-jni-method).

Comment: This is easier. Thanks @Doron Yakovlev-Golani

Answer (score 2):

You should use [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) to generate declaration header for your functions. Assuming method `GetData` is located in class `com.example.hellojni.HelloJni` it would be:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_hellojni_HelloJni
 * Method:    GetData
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Vector;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_GetData
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

then in you implementation file (ie. test.cpp):

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_GetData(JNIEnv *env , jclass, jstring str) {

  // Find Class for Vector
  jclass clsVec = env->FindClass("java/util/Vector");

  // Get its constructor method
  jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(clsVec, "<init>", "()V");

  // Create new Vector object
  jobject objVec = env->NewObject(clsVec, constructor, "");

  // Get addElement method
  jmethodID vecAdd = env->GetMethodID(clsVec, "addElement", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V");

  // Add new string (created locally)
  jstring retStr = env->NewStringUTF("Whatever");
  env->CallVoidMethod(objVec, vecAdd, retStr);

  // Add string from parameter
  env->CallVoidMethod(objVec, vecAdd, str);

  // Always release local references.
  env->DeleteLocalRef(clsVec);

  return objVec;
}
```

Comment: jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(clsVec, "<init>", "()V");  Can you please explain what does "()V" mean?

Comment: Thanks @luskan for helping me out

Comment: @jeff this is a signature for constructor, `()` means zero parameters, and `V` means returns void. Constructors have no return values, but `GetMethodID` requires specifying `<init>` as method name and void `V` as return type to get constructor.